# android how to make a text file viewer?

Tags: android, file, text

This is a concept problem.
I see many text file viewer in android market. They are able to open a txt file with thousand of words. The viewer shows the text content in hundred of pages, and allow go back to previous page, go to next page, etc.
My problem is, as the length of word are different. If you want to go to page 50, do you have to start from page 1 and check how many words is needed to fit in page 1 to page 49, then you know the first English word in page 50?
And when you go back one page, you don't know the first word of page 49. Again, how can I find it out efficiently?
Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you store each page in an object then save the hole document in ArrayList for example?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have experience with text viewers, the best approach is webView based application. You can easily add some HTML/CSS to the text and pass it to web view. WebKit will do all the job. For example, hyphenation. Doing it yourself is kinda tricky, specially for multiple languages. WebKit can do it for your.

Speaking about your concept without WebKit - is it important to let user to change font? If yes, you should re-parse document on every changing, I guess. Anyway, the easiest way is to use percentage and show not exact page, but place that is very near. For example, you can find out the size of one page in pro-cents of the document and use it to get needed portions to show.

Good luck in your research!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Let me ask a simpler question. I see some text viewer.They can read eng text (fixed text size) and display it on screen. It allow use finger to scroll up and down. One typical usage to showing very long license txt. Can anyone tell me how they implement it? the widgets used? etc, thanks